# WSO2 Identity Server User Portal and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, dashboard, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a multi tenant WSO2 IS 5.10 deployed for testing. I have configured three tenants, all connected to an Active Directory. Authentication and claims mappings work fine for SP's that i create. I am trying to enable the new user portal for users coming from the AD user stores. I have added them to the Portal permission, but at logon, users from the AD user stores all get a permission denied page. Is this scenario supported ?  Is there any specific configuration needed to make this work. Any thoughts or comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Does these users have the internal_login scope assigned to them?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up accidentally figuring out that the SCIM properties needed to be appropriately mapped to AD properties.  This document was helpful in figuring out why password change did not work https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-user-stores-for-scim-2.0-based-inbound-provisioning/#configuring-user-stores-for-scim-20-based-inbound-provisioning . Once that was fixed, the rest worked as expected.  For secondary stores and primary stores to work, you need to map both the internal default attribute as well as a second attribute targeting the AD user store.